# Creating custom SQL data source using standard protocol

Tags: database, networking, odbc

**Problem**

I have a custom data source (an inhouse system) which I would like to access as a standard data source. I am looking for a solution to provide standard SQL-like accessors so that the data source can be used from different report engines, Excel, MS access, maybe standard web frontends and off-the-shelf data management tool. In other words, I would like off-the-shelf support for ODBC, JDBC and whatnot, without having to implement support for all these drivers myself.

**What I have been doing so far**

I have successfully used the SQLite virtual table mechanism to provide access to the data source using a standard SQLite driver. SQLite will take care of the SQL query parsing, table metadata translation (provided by my extension) and manage the SQL parts that my data source does not support (aggregates, complex joins and updates, etc).

However, what I don't get with SQLite is network support. SQLite is an embedded database engine which works very well with my data source, but although it has ODBC and JDBC support, it has no wire protocol. Embedding my custom data source in the client process is not an option, since the data source has very strict runtime restrictions (among other restrictions).

**What I am considering**

*1. Networked SQLite*

The obvious solution is to look at if it is possible to [network the SQLite data source](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteNetwork). However, the network options does not seem well supported, especially not with client drivers (i.e. not at all).

*2. MySQL storage engine*

I have been looking at replacing the SQLite virtual table driver with a MySQL [storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/custom-engine.html) (30 minutes of reading API specs gives me a gut feeling the APIs are quite similar). I have three concerns:

- Process control. My data source is a system which wants to manage its own processes. I would prefer to be the one responsible for service provisioning.
- Running the whole MySQL server looks like overkill from an IT adminstration point of view. An embedded networked server would suffice. I already got the network server (it's already a web service process).
- Licensing. MySQL looks like GPL or expensive. I did not find anything conclusive on what license requirements this setup would force me into.

*3. Mimicking a known network protocol*

I have been looking into mimicking "known" protocols such as MySQL wire protocol or MSSQL ([freeTDS](http://www.freetds.org) is a good source). However the amount of readily available solutions look scarce, and I might have to roll my own if I go down this path, which is probably a lot of work.

I am looking for other options on how to do this. Right now, I am investigating if it is possible to choose #2 and use an interface between my data source and the storage engine (e.g. [0mq](http://www.zeromq.org) or some network protocol). I believe it is doable, but I am very interested in easier solutions. Has anyone out there done something similar (with success)?